# JSON.parse not parsing out token object?

Tags: node.js, json, jsonparser

OK, so I'm losing my mind over this one:

I'm using node's request module to do a POST. (I know that that module has been deprecated, but it's what this pre-existing solution I'm working on is using.)

The POST is getting back the response.body as a JSON object.  If I stringify the body, I get:

{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMDAwMDU0NCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ3cy1jbGllbnQtaW5mbyIsImV4cCI6MTY0NTE5MzgxMywiZW1haWwiOiJkbF9hcHBzdmNzX2RldkBjZXJuZXIuY29tIn0.dEH3s5QxgkmlHC2OYvTEA1WxlVLE4t-QCsa191hhxEg"}

Yet, for some reason, if I try to assign body.token, I get "token is not defined".

I've even used Postman to perform the same request.  It shows that the response's content-type is application/json.  And it shows the exact same response body. So it doesn't seem to be a case where the server isn't returning valid json in the body.

I just can't figure out why json.parse won't parse this thing.   I've tried stringifying it and reparsing and I get the same thing.

JSON.parse doesn't actually throw an error

I even tried doing:

```
        const stringified = '{ \"token\":\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMDAwMDU0NCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ3cy1jbGllbnQtaW5mbyIsImV4cCI6MTY0NTE5MzQzNywiZW1haWwiOiJkbF9hcHBzdmNzX2RldkBjZXJuZXIuY29tIn0.g7RNs5zzVvXyZ71uE63QunleMtuki2hNjYka61HfGNQ\"}';
        let stringifiedandreparsed;
        try {
          stringifiedandreparsed = JSON.parse(stringified);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error('Exception thrown while parsing string into object');
        }
        console.log('stringifiedandreparsed type is ' + typeof(stringifiedandreparsed));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(stringifiedandreparsed));
        token = stringifiedandreparsed.token;
```

And it still blows up on that last line.

Any thoughts? I'd hate to have to do some sort of string-matching/grepping in order to assign the token.

Thanks!

======  UPDATE ========

```
 async getAuthToken() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const jsonParamsObj = {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
      };
      request.post({
        url: `${this.baseUrl}${this.authServicePath}`,
        body: jsonParamsObj,
        json: true,
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        if (response.statusCode === 200 && response.body) {
          try {
            const body = response.body;
            console.info('body = ' + body);
            console.info('stringified body = ' + JSON.stringify(body));
            token = response.body.token;
            console.info('Token returned = ' + token);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error while parsing LON API Token object:  ' +
              err.message + '  ' + err.stack);
            return reject(err);
          }
          return resolve(token);
        } else {
          return reject( new Error('Unexpected response received from LON API ' +
            'token service: ' +
            JSON.stringify(response)));
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Console results:

08:30:04 AM CST info: body = [object Object]

08:30:04 AM CST info: stringified body = {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMDAwMDU0NCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ3cy1jbGllbnQtaW5mbyIsImV4cCI6MTY0NTE5NTUwNCwiZW1haWwiOiJkbF9hcHBzdmNzX2RldkBjZXJuZXIuY29tIn0.s-vPoDqXCeOiSNxrCDPdDce05D07iuNq6ana77Yyxzc"}

08:30:04 AM CST error: Error while parsing LON API Token object:  token is not defined  ReferenceError: token is not defined

(And it points to the line "token = response.body.token" as being the point of error.)

Comment: `JSON.parse(stringified).token` gives me the token. In fact, your code works for me just fine. Can you share a [mcve] that shows this code not working?

Comment: The example you've provided seems to work just fine. Also if you use `request` with callback and `json` option specified it should serialize a response for you as a third argument in provided callback.

Comment: ```JSON.parse(stringified)``` worked for me, there must be another catch.

Comment: updated the post with some code

Comment: I've tried the example in the console and it's working fine, I didn't get the error

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

That line... "token = response.body.token".

I thought I'd had that "token" variable assigned as a private variable for the entire class (similar to another class that I have).  However, that's not how we're going to handle the token in this class.  We're returning it, not storing it within the class itself for re-use.

Once I added a "let token;" to the callback function, it started working.

Thanks!